# How to calculate $y^T \mbox{diag}(A^T B A) \,y$ efficiently?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to calculate $$y^T \mbox{diag}(A^T B A) \,y$$ where

- $y$ is a $n \times  1$ vector.
- $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix where $n \gg m$.
- $B$ is a $m \times m$ symmetric positive definite matrix; the Cholesky decomposition $B = LL^T$ is precomputed if it is needed.

Is it possible to calculate the above expression at a cost of $O(m n)$ flops?

Comment: What is $\mbox{diag} (\cdot)$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo diag(.) is the diagonal of the matrix.

Comment: Is $\mbox{diag} (A)$ a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are $a_{11}, a_{22}, \dots, a_{nn}$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathrm y^\top \mbox{diag}(\mathrm A^\top \mathrm B \,\mathrm A) \,\mathrm y = \sum_{k=1}^n \mathrm e_k^\top\mathrm A^\top \mathrm B \,\mathrm A \,\mathrm e_k \, y_k^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n \mathrm a_k^\top \mathrm B \, \mathrm a_k \, y_k^2$$

where $\mathrm a_k \in \mathbb R^m$ is the $k$-th column of $\rm A$. Since each $\mathrm a_k^\top \mathrm B \, \mathrm a_k$ costs $\mathcal O (m^2)$ operations, the total computational cost is $\mathcal O (m^2 n)$ operations.

However, if $\rm B$ is a **diagonal** matrix, then each $\mathrm a_k^\top \mathrm B \, \mathrm a_k$ only costs $\mathcal O (m)$ operations, and the total computational cost is $\mathcal O (m n)$ operations.